# How to combine two SQL queries into one and display in foreach loop PHP

Tags: php, mysql, join, foreach, html-table

I am trying to display two specific persons (a couples income) in a table (by foreach loop PHP). Each person should be shown in a column and the income per row.

To connect the couple/persons I have created a table `j_b_controller` which can join the couples together by a `joint_budget_id`. The `j_b_controller` also has a `position_order` column to control where to put the person1 and person2. Person1 have position_order = 1 and person2 = 2.

When one of the accounts log on I start this session

```
$_SESSION['budget_id'] = $jointbudget['joint_budget_id'];
```

An example: the income table look like this

- person1 have income1, income2, income 3 and income 5.
- person2 have income1
- The amount in income1 for each person is not the same.
- Each income have its own specific `row_type_id` so `income1` has `row_type_id = 1`.

[Income table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrqV3.png)

| id | name | account_id | amount | note | row_type_id | date_added |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Income1 | 1 | 14000.99 |  | 1 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | Income2 | 1 | 1900.99 |  | 2 | 2022-01-03 00:00:00 |
| 3 | Income3 | 1 | 3269.99 |  | 3 | 2022-01-06 00:00:00 |
| 4 | Income1 | 2 | 5200.99 |  | 1 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 5 | Income5 | 1 | 130.99 |  | 5 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |

The j_b_controller table looks like this

- Person1 has joint_budget_id = 1 and position_order = 1
- Person2 has joint_budget_id = 1 and position_order = 2

[j_b_controller table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OqW2.png)

| id | account_id | joint_budget_id | accept_invitation | position_order | date_added |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |  | 1 | 2022-02-10 11:45:22 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |  | 2 | 2022-02-11 11:45:24 |

Everything should be displayed in a HTML table (PHP foreach loop)

ORDER BY row_type_id

| Person 1 | Person 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Income1 | Income1 |
| Income2 | Empty |
| Income3 | Empty |
| Income5 | Empty |

Hopefully you can see the picture below
[image: HTML Table]

The two SQL queries that should be joined/unioned is

```
//Select incomes from person with position_order = 1
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT i.id, i.name, i.amount AS p2_amount, i.row_type_id FROM incomes i JOIN j_b_controller jb ON i.account_id = jb.account_id AND jb.joint_budget_id = ? AND jb.position_order = **1** ORDER BY i.id AND i.row_type_id ASC');
    $stmt->execute([$_SESSION['budget_id']]);
    $income_rows_122s = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and

```
//Select incomes from person with position_order = 2
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT i.id, i.name, i.amount AS p2_amount, i.row_type_id FROM incomes i JOIN j_b_controller jb ON i.account_id = jb.account_id AND jb.joint_budget_id = ? AND jb.position_order = **2** ORDER BY i.id AND i.row_type_id ASC');
    $stmt->execute([$_SESSION['budget_id']]);
    $income_rows_122s = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I have already tried to use UNION the two and I have tried to make a subquery

My subquery is the closed I got so far but with the subquery I can only return 1 row for person2.. and it is repeated as many times as Person1 have incomes.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT i.*, i.amount AS p1_amount, (SELECT amount FROM incomes i JOIN j_b_controller jb ON i.account_id = jb.account_id AND jb.joint_budget_id = ? AND jb.position_order = 2 ORDER BY i.id AND i.row_type_id ASC) AS p2_amount FROM incomes i JOIN  j_b_controller jb ON i.account_id = jb.account_id AND jb.joint_budget_id = ? AND jb.position_order = 1 ORDER BY i.id AND i.row_type_id ASC');
    $stmt->execute([$_SESSION['budget_id'], $_SESSION['budget_id']]);
    $income_rows_1s = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

My foreach looks like this

```
<tbody>
                <?php if (empty($income_rows_1s)) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="8" style="text-align:center;">There are no objects</td>
                    </tr>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <?php foreach ($income_rows_1s as $income_rows_1) : ?>
                       
                        <?php if (empty($income_rows_1['row_type_id'])) :?>


                        <?php else : ?>
                            <tr role="row" class="item" data-modal=".incomeInfo<?= md5($income_rows_1['row_type_id']) ?>">
                                <td role="gridcell" class="table-edit-link"></td>
                                <td role="gridcell" class="table-view-link"><a href="#"><?= $income_rows_1['name'] ?></a></td>
                                <?php if (empty($income_rows_1['p1_amount']) or ($income_rows_1['p1_amount']) == 0.00) :  ?>
                                    <td role="gridcell"></td>
                                <?php else : ?>
                                <td role="gridcell"><?= number_format($income_rows_1['p1_amount'], $decimals, ',', '.'); ?></td>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if (empty($income_rows_1['row_type_id']) or (empty($income_rows_1['p2_amount']) or ($income_rows_1['p2_amount']) == 0.00)) : ?>
                                    <td role="gridcell"></td>
                                 <?php else : ?>
                                <td role="gridcell"><?= number_format($income_rows_1['p2_amount'], $decimals, ',', '.'); ?></td>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <td role="gridcell"><?= number_format(($income_rows_1['p1_amount'] + $income_rows_1['p2_amount']), $decimals, ',', '.') ?></td>
                                <td role="gridcell"><?= number_format(($income_rows_1['p1_amount'] + $income_rows_1['p2_amount']) * 12, $decimals, ',', '.') ?></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </tbody>
```

The result looks like this (picture)
[image: HTML Table]

Person2 should only have income1 shown 1 time and the rest is empty. If person2 had income 6 then the income6 row for person1 would be empty and then person2 had the income6 amount in the table.

Hopefully this make sence. I am NOT a skilled/educated programmer but I like to program a bit in my spare time.

Comment: Why are you not using a where clause to select by `position_order`?

Comment: Try to figure out the proper SQL query first - this is not a problem of PHP or any HTML table

Comment: I'm not quite sure how `row_type_id` is supposed to work - what happens when Person 1 has a different value for `row_type_id` than Person 2?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I did not see any different result between AND and WHERE but you are correct it should be WHERE clause

Comment: @RobEyre row_type_id could also be called ` income_type_id`. It is used to ORDER BY  and group person1 income1 to person2 income1. Every person can only have a specific income one time but can have income1 to income 999. It could also be that person1 have income6 and income7 and person2 have income1, income2, income3 and income5.

Comment: Ah, OK.  I updated my answer to group and order by row_type_id rather than income name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you your desired result set in one query:

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(i.row_type_id, 'Total') AS Name,
    SUM(IF(jb.position_order = 1, i.amount, NULL)) AS "Person 1",
    SUM(IF(jb.position_order = 2, i.amount, NULL)) AS "Person 2"
FROM incomes i
INNER JOIN j_b_controller jb ON i.account_id = jb.account_id
WHERE jb.joint_budget_id = 1
GROUP BY i.row_type_id WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY ISNULL(i.row_type_id), i.row_type_id
```

result:

```
+---------+----------+----------+
| Name    | Person 1 | Person 2 |
+---------+----------+----------+
| 1       | 14000.99 |  5200.99 |
| 2       |  1900.99 |     NULL |
| 3       |  3269.99 |     NULL |
| 5       |   130.99 |     NULL |
| Total   | 19302.96 |  5200.99 |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

In your PHP code, you can check for NULL values when iterating your table.

Comment: A small modification and it worked!
`SELECT i.id, i.name, SUM(IF(jb.position_order = 1, i.amount, NULL)) AS p1_amount, SUM(IF(jb.position_order = 2, i.amount, NULL)) AS p2_amount FROM incomes i INNER JOIN j_b_controller jb ON i.account_id = jb.account_id WHERE jb.joint_budget_id = ? GROUP BY i.row_type_id ORDER BY ISNULL(i.row_type_id), i.row_type_id ASC`
Thank you!
I got an error when using WITH ROLLUP and ORDER BY together.

Answer (score -1):

If i understand you right, youre searching for something like this?

```
SELECT i.amount AS p1_amount, ii.amount AS p2_amount FROM incomes i 
JOIN j_b_controller jb ON i.account_id = jb.account_id AND jb.joint_budget_id = ? AND jb.position_order = **1** 
LEFT JOIN incomes ii ON ii.account_id = jb.account_id AND jb.joint_budget_id = ? AND jb.position_order = **2** 
ORDER BY i.id AND i.row_type_id ASC, ii.id AND ii.row_type_id ASC;
```